# get Image src from string without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html

I have a **STRING** (Not in my document) like

```
<img src="http://www.blogcdn.com/www.engadget.com/media/2013/10/bear-extender-    samsungativ_thumbnail.jpg"> Freedom is a wonderful thing and the folks at BearExtender want Microsoft users to enjoy more of it. Its new 1,200mW USB WiFi booster for PCs finally caught up with the Mac version, which extends WiFi range up to four times more than usual. One lucky reader will get to savor this new found freedom ...<div>
```

I want to strip off the source of the first image in the string. I know I can do it using jquery by using:
`String.find('img').first().attr('src');`

How can I achieve the same thing WITHOUT jquery?

Comment: If you don't want to use jQuery, why tag the question with jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you want to do a few plain JS tests on it to strip out the src from there like so:

```
var str = '<img src="http://www.blogcdn.com/www.engadget.com/media/2013/10/bear-extender-    samsungativ_thumbnail.jpg"> Freedom is a wonderful thing and the folks at BearExtender want Microsoft users to enjoy more of it. Its new 1,200mW USB WiFi booster for PCs finally caught up with the Mac version, which extends WiFi range up to four times more than usual. One lucky reader will get to savor this new found freedom ...<div>'

var imgExists = str.indexOf('<img src="');

if (imgExists > -1) {
    var i = imgExists + 10;

    str = str.substr(i);
    str = str.substr(0, str.indexOf('"'));
    alert(str); 
     // returns = http://www.blogcdn.com/www.engadget.com/media/2013/10/bear-extender-    samsungativ_thumbnail.jpg 

    // to remove all the spaces you might also want to do another replace after the last 2 substr's
    // str = str.replace(/\s/g, ''); 
}
```

**[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DgVQ3/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can get it with:

```
var i = '<img src="http://www.blogcdn.com/www.engadget.com/media/2013/10/bear-extender-    samsungativ_thumbnail.jpg"> Freedom is a wonderful thing and the folks at BearExtender want Microsoft users to enjoy more of it. Its new 1,200mW USB WiFi booster for PCs finally caught up with the Mac version, which extends WiFi range up to four times more than usual. One lucky reader will get to savor this new found freedom ...<div>';
    alert(i.substring(i.indexOf('http'), i.lastIndexOf('"')));
```

Answer (score 0):

i can see you are using this `img` in `div`. Set the `id` param in the `div` to `id="imgDiv"`. Then you can use this syntax to solve the problem :

```
<script>
  var div = document.getElementById("imgDiv");
  var image = div.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
  alert(image.src);
</script>
```

Comment: Again, I don't have it in my HTML code. As I said, its a string.